# Remove kernel module in use

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, kernel-modules, bluetooth

I would like to remove some kernel module (bluetooth) without rebooting my device.

When I'm trying to remove it, a fatal error appears.

```
# modprobe -rf btbcm
modprobe: FATAL: Module btbcm is in use.
```

I know that I have some dependences

```
root@raspberrypi:~# modprobe -D btbcm
insmod /lib/modules/5.10.17-v7+/kernel/net/rfkill/rfkill.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.10.17-v7+/kernel/crypto/ecc.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.10.17-v7+/kernel/crypto/ecdh_generic.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.10.17-v7+/kernel/net/bluetooth/bluetooth.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.10.17-v7+/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btbcm.ko
```

When I tried to remove any other module specified here, the same error appeared.

I turned down bluetoothd when I was trying to remove the module.

Blacklist seems not be the good solution because it needs a device reboot to be enabled.

What can I do to remove my kernel module ?

Comment: A process could be using (indirectly) that module. Stop bluetooth services and you should be able to remove it. Something like `sudo systemctl stop hciuart.service` might do it.

Answer (score 1):

`modprobe --remove-dependencies -f btbcm` should remove the dependencies.

`-D` just lists the dependencies *of* btbcm, not the modules using it.

Comment: What do I need to do to find all services using my module ?

Comment: `lsmod` should list them